# Or operator equivalent using mustache.js

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

Ok, so I know that mustache templates don't have logic, but how do I implement this:

```
<?php
  if ($a || $b) {
    echo $c, $d, $e;
  }
?>
```

... using mustache template syntax? The best I can come up with is this:

```
{{#a}}
  {{c}}{{d}}{{e}}
{{/a}}
{{^#a}}
  {{#b}}
    {{c}}{{d}}{{e}}
  {{/b}}
{{/a}}
```

... which is obviously hideous and requires me to duplicate anything inside the 'if'.

Any ideas?

Comment: <jerk answer>use a templating engine with logic?</jerk answer>. Seriously thought have you tried using a function to implant the logic and putting the function into the template data object

Answer (score 15):

Mustache expressly forbids things like this. That's logic, and you're trying to put it in your template :)

The appropriate way would be to move the logic to your ViewModel or View object:

```
<?php
class MyView {
    public $a;
    public $b;
    public function aOrB() {
        return $this->a || $this->b;
    }
}
```

But if it were me, I'd name that function something like `hasFoo` or `showBar`, so it has a bit of semantic meaning.

Because you're handling the "should I show this block?" logic in your View or ViewModel, you're back to a normal section in your template:

```
{{#aOrB}}
  {{c}}{{d}}{{e}}
{{/aOrB}}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the record, that is the only way to do it with mustache. As for now (mustache 5, I believe) there is no better solution.